# spell check in Rstudio

Tags: linux, rstudio, spell-checking, hunspell

How to configure and use spell check in Rstudio? In the tools>Global option>spelling I have set the main dictionary language as English(US) and custom dictionary as en_us from "/usr/lib/rstudio/resources/dictionaries/en_US.dic".
Still I do not see any indication (such as red make) on wrong spellings!!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

RStudio does not have an as-you-type spell checker; you'll have to invoke spell checking manually. To do this, go to the Edit menu and choose Check Spelling, or press F7.

Note that spell checking is not performed on code files, only on document files (i.e. you won't get spell checking an .R file, but you will in an .Rmd file).

Comment: Thanks. It is disappointing that spell-check can't be done on .R file. Other editor such as "Eclipse" have this feature. I hope RStudio will include it.

Comment: Indeed. Spellcheck on comments in R files would be a nice addition.

Comment: as well as "as-you-type" spell checker, would be a nice feature to have

Comment: similar/maybe duplicate post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36728061/how-can-i-use-spell-check-in-rmarkdown

Comment: This response is outdated, R Studio now has spell check in real time.

Answer (score 2):

I recently spotted live, on-the-fly spell checking in OSX v.1.3.118 and later, which can be downloaded from https://dailies.rstudio.com/

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this still available?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add custom spell checker and want to be persistent across the Rstudio installations, you can create a [hunspell](https://github.com/hunspell/hunspell) dictionary. Here is what I did:

1. Create a hunspell dictionary (a nice approach is [here](https://www.suares.com/?page_id=25&news_id=233))

   1. Create a text document where the first line is the number of words in the dictionary and the rest of the lines are the words in the dictionary. Make sure the last line is empty.

      [image]
   2. Save the dictionary with `.dic` extension.
2. Add the dictionary to Rstudio from `Tools > Global Options... > Spelling > Add...`. (More info is [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200551916))
3. Restart Rstudio. Later, when you update the dictionary file, you may need to Remove the dictionary and Add it again, then restart.