# How can I use spell check in Rmarkdown?

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, spelling

I want to write a report with Rmarkdown. However, I am a little worried about my spelling. I hope there is a package installed in my Rstudio which can automatically help me spell check.

So, is there such a package or is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Here are three ways to access spell checking in an rMarkdown document in rstudio:

1. A spell check button to the right of the save button (with "ABC" and a check mark).
2. Edit > Check Spelling...
3. The `F7` key

A keyboard alternative to option 2 is `alt + e + s`. That is, while holding down the `alt` key, type `e` followed by `s`.

Comment: As of Version 1.0.143 on Windows I don't see the "ABC" and check mark or Edit > Check Spelling... F7 is the right shortcut but isn't doing anything for me right now.

Comment: Hey @StevenMortimer I just tried with 1.0.143 at home, and the abc checkmark etc are still there. My guess is that you don't aren't using the proper file type. If you go to `file > new File > Rmarkdown` or `file > new File > Sweave` or Rpresentation, (depending on what document you are trying to create) you should see the checkmark. The spellcheck is not activated for .R script files.

Comment: @Imo You are right that those spell checking options only appear if you are looking at an RMarkdown document.

Comment: It would be cool to spell check in all file types, not just rMarkdown.

Comment: Is there a possibility to only check spelling outside of code blocks? In an Rmd file I mostly type explanatory text around code and output, and only the explanatory text needs spell checking. But now, if you simply run the spell check, it also checks all of the code.

Comment: As of Rstudio 1.2.5033, the answer as fas as I can tell is "no." (`Global Options > Spellling` does not include this as an option) Version 1.3 was recently released. I did not see anything about improved spell checking in their release notes. This would be a nice improvement. You could request such a feature on their [Github page](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio).

Answer (score 1):

There is Real Time Spellchecking since RStudio 1.3:
https://blog.rstudio.com/2020/02/11/rstudio-1-3-preview-real-time-spellchecking/