# Rstudio spell checker in spanish

Tags: r, r-markdown

I want to write a report in rmarkdown or rsweave, but I need an automatic spell checker in spanish. The document I am writing has the following sentence in Spanish: `La niña ve películas de ciencia ficcion cuando llueve`. The spell checker works but for English texts. See this link 
[How can I use spell check in Rmarkdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36728061/how-can-i-use-spell-check-in-rmarkdown). There is some way to use the spell checker but in Spanish, since the correct word in Spanish is `ficción` with `ó` not `fiction` as it comes out by clicking on ABC or using `F7`

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First go to Tools-> Global options -> Spelling. Then install the dictionary in Spanish and click on apply.

[image]

Now you can open a new file in rmarkdown or rsweave. And have an automatic spelling corrector by clicking on ABC. I think it's very useful for the entire Spanish-speaking community that uses Rstudio to make reports.

[image]