# How to spellcheck R comments with RStudio on R source files?

Tags: rstudio

How to conveniently spellcheck R comments with RStudio on R source files?

I am writing a package and I want it to look professional. Thanks to Oxygen, all package's documentation lives in R comments, which by default is excluded from spell checking. So even if spell checking functionality does exist in RStudio, I don't know how to use it.

Comment: similar/maybe duplicate post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36728061/how-can-i-use-spell-check-in-rmarkdown

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31653319/spell-check-in-rstudio

Comment: Not a duplicate of those. RStudio doesn't seem to allow spellcheck on .R (aka source) files.

Answer (score 4):

The `spelling` package is great for this: https://github.com/ropensci/spelling.

```
devtools::install_github("ropensci/spelling")
spelling::spell_check_package() # path to package Project
```

Answer (score 2):

RStudio 1.3 will include this feature; and it is possible to already try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is moot now that Rstudio has spellcheck for spin documents!

So, I write a lot of my lessons and examples for teaching using spin rather than markdown. It just makes for an easier flow. The problem is that there is no spell-check in a spin document, much like your package documentation example.
What I have resorted to is using the terminal then running a command line spellchecker on the document.

I'm on linux so here is my workflow.

1. save the file I am working let's say `example_lesson.R` (typos and all)
2. open the terminal pane of Rstudio and cd to the right folder
3. make sure the file `example_lesson.R` is there
4. run the spell-checker

```
> aspell check example_lesson.R
```

Once I'm done with aspell, I go back to the editor window in Rstudio and it updates what I am working on with the spell-checked version. I spin it and I am done.

I've only tested with small examples, but it has worked thus far. Your mileage may vary. Hope that helps.